# Using WPF converters to translate xpath node existence to Visible/Hidden/Collapsed

Tags: wpf, xpath, ivalueconverter

I've been successfully using Converters to convert boolean values in WPF to an appropriate property e.g. Hidden/Collapsed/Visible for hiding and showing a control.

I'd like to achieve the same thing using the existence of an xpath node- the sort of path you'd test for in XSLT with something like:

`<xsl:if test="/SomeNode/Exists"></xsl:if>`

If the node exists, I want the converter to output "Visible" and if not "Hidden" or "Collapsed".

Anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a converter, which will take the XPath query as [ConverterParameter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.binding.converterparameter.aspx).

[Some more info.](http://www.infosysblogs.com/microsoft/2008/04/wpf_passing_string_to_converte.html)

I don't think there is much more we can do aside from writing the code for you :)

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion- it certainly helped me towards finding the answer.

Testing that the parameter passed to it was of type "string" was sufficient to identify it as an XML node.

The only nuance that I needed to get to the solution was that the control binding never actually fired the converter if the XPath didn't find an XML node.  The answer was to add a  `FallbackValue="Collapsed"` to the binding to ensure that the control didn't appear even if the binding failed to run the converter.